# What sort of implementation dependent limits for glPointSize can one expect from modern graphics cards?

Tags: opengl

As noted [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPointSize.xml#notes), when rendering using the GL_POINTS primitive, there is an implementation dependent limit to the point size range.

I intend to use GL_POINTS for fast billboard rendering of particles, so I am dependent on the point size range to be sufficiently large to visualize perspective scaling.

I would consider for example the range provided by my graphics card (1-255), to be sufficient, since usually, particles are not close enough to the camera to exceed 255 pixels in diameter.

Are there any commonly used graphics cards that do not provide such a large range of points sizes?

Are there any (reasonably modern) graphics cards that do not allow for points larger than one pixel at all?

Comment: consider using one of the online databases to look up that type of info such as this one with give a nice graph showing sizes and distribution: https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=pointSizeRange[1]&platform=windows

Comment: @pmw1234 I wasn't aware that such a site existed. Thank you!